# Set default timezone in Yii

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, yii, timezone

I am using following config for timezone in **config.php**

```
'timeZone' => 'UTC',
```

It is working fine and all dates are stored in database according to **UTC**. Now each user has its own timezone in his/her profile like **UTC+5**, **UTC-5**, **UTC+0**, etc.

Now how can I show dates in reports according to user timezone. I used active record to fetch records from database. Is there any general way for all queries or we have to convert date to user timezone each time manually in php ??

Thanks.

Comment: how you are storing date in table?

Comment: UTC date is stored in database like this 'yy-mm-dd'

Comment: Did you ever find a good answer to your question? Which approach did you finally use?

Answer (score 5):

You can set Timezone in Yii by adding below value in main.php file of config

```
return array(   
  'timeZone' => 'Asia/Kolkata',
 )
```

For time zone list in PHP : http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php

Answer (score 2):

After loading user data try:

> ```
> Yii:app()->timeZone = $userTimezone;
> ```

where $userTimezone - is loaded user timezone from db. It's for using in Yii

OR you can set timezone in mysql ones by:

> ```
> Yii::app()->db->createCommand('SET time_zone = <timezonename>')->execute()
> ```

and all TIMESTAMP fields will be in setted timezone for current session

Answer (score 2):

You can use afterFind to change the time accordingly

```
public function afterFind()
{
    //apply your logic here
    $zone = Yii:app()->timeZone;

    // I don't know code to change time zone, so I assume there is a function named "functionToChangeTimeZone"
    $this->time = functionToChangeTimeZone($this->time , $zone);

    return parent::afterFind();
}
```

now every record will have there time zone changed according their settings