# yii 1: CDbExpression does not use the date default timezone

Tags: php, yii

I have an app that changes the timezone depending on facility location. I have the timezone data for each facility.

Before I used the YII CDbExpression to generate date.
I set the timezone first:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Australia/Sydney');
```

or

```
date_default_timezone_set('Australia/Perth');
```

And while debugging, I also show the timezone to check the application change it:

```
date_default_timezone_get();
```

But I found out that YII CDbExpression still produces dates on the server default timezone.

Is there a special way to change the timezone in YII to take effect on CDbExpression?

Comment: See this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19763955/set-default-timezone-in-yii

Comment: Found a solution, just have to use native date() function instead of using CDbExpression. To avoid changing the database timezone. Just want to work the timezone solution on php.